# ROS publisher Errors?

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I work with ROS Jade in Eclipse and communicate withh V-REP.
And I have the following problem:
Most of the times my programmruns without problems,
but sometimes when I run it the following two different kind of hang ups appear.

Error Type 1:

```
[31m[FATAL] [1446845672.704039636]: ASSERTION FAILED
    file = /opt/ros/jade/include/ros/publisher.h
    line = 108
    cond = false
    message = [0m
```

The error happens, when I want to publish a twist  message.
Also extracting the topicname from this publisher leads to this error.
So I suspect, the publisher randomly has problems with the topic?!
Any ideas why?

Error Type 2:
The program crashes.
The debugger of eclipse shows corresponding call structure:

```
Thread #2 [fccf_node] 17359 [core: 3] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
    __memcpy_sse2_unaligned() at memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:36 0x7ffff66dfffe  
    ros::Header::write() at 0x7ffff6226e08  
    ros::Connection::writeHeader() at 0x7ffff7b0b4ec    
    ros::TransportSubscriberLink::handleHeader() at 0x7ffff7b715e4  
    ros::ConnectionManager::onConnectionHeaderReceived() at 0x7ffff7b592d3  
    ros::Connection::onHeaderRead() at 0x7ffff7b0ca17   
    ros::Connection::readTransport() at 0x7ffff7b09dca  
    ros::Connection::read() at 0x7ffff7b0a49d   
    ros::Connection::initialize() at 0x7ffff7b0a761 
    ros::ConnectionManager::tcprosAcceptConnection() at 0x7ffff7b5b4e1  
    ros::TransportTCP::socketUpdate() at 0x7ffff7b68af7 
    ros::PollSet::update() at 0x7ffff7b9521e    
    ros::PollManager::threadFunc() at 0x7ffff7b39925    
    0x7ffff6017a4a  
    start_thread() at pthread_create.c:312 0x7ffff5df6182   
    clone() at clone.S:111 0x7ffff674247d
```

No ideda why it's hanging...
Maybe you have?

Both error appear everytime they appear at their same spot at the beginning of the program.
If the program runs smoothly it keeps running.
If it crashes, it crashes at the beginning.

Unfortunately I cannot provide a  minimal sample, as I cannot reproduce the error.
It appears randomly.
I use:

```
 * /rosdistro: jade
 * /rosversion: 1.11.13
GNU GCC : gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
V-REP: V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_2_1_64_Linux
```

I have no clue anymore.
Thanks in advance for your help!!!
You are the best!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220566/ros-publisher-errors?!/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-11-06**:
Please add more details to your question including your platform, how you've installed and a minimal example of how to reproduce your issue.

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2015-11-09**:
I added the platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue.
The error was some memory leakage, that produced the crashing of the publisher.

---

Originally posted by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) with karma: 170 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0